# SQL detecting null value and change query

Tags: c#, sql, mysql

i am using c# and mssql. i send parameters from c# to sql and execute a query but sometimes it comes null values. i m using sql like function. it is great for string values but has problems with bool. for example
bool b = NULL
query executes like that: .... WHERE B LIKE '%%'
and it never returns a value.
i want to detect null value and change query if b is null the query must be like that
...... WHERE B IS NOT NULL
i could change this in c# code but there are some other parameters like that it could be easier in sql if it is possible

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server supports the standard SQL [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244(SQL.80).aspx) function; try wrapping your boolean values in a coalesce call, e.g. WHERE COALESCE(bool_value, '') LIKE '%%'

Answer (score 1):

Use [parameterized queries](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/) and all of this is taken care of for you.